# Add Items in listBox (API)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, listbox

I just want to add a wostringstream (tmp) Item to my listBox in C++. Here is the way I tried:

```
 for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    tmp<<hex<<m_device_info.Adress.rgBytes[i];
    if (i<5)
     tmp<<L":";
 }
listBox2->Items->Add(tmp.str());
```

The Error I get is:

> "error C2664:'System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::ObjectCollection::Add'
>   convert 'wchar_t' in 'system::object ^' not possible"

Somebody has a clue?

Comment: What is not working? Is 'tmp' the wostringstream?

Comment: yes, 'tmp' is wostringstream. I just want to write tmp to a string variable, which should allow me to import my data as a item of my listbox

Comment: tmp.str() gets you a string object

Comment: but if I try to add it to my listbox than I get a error of these part: listBox2->Items->Add(tmp.str());

Comment: What's the error ? I'm guessing you need to us tmp.str().c_str()

Comment: "error C2664:'System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::ObjectCollection::Add' convert 'wchar_t' in 'system::object ^' not possible"

Comment: also tried tmp.str().c_str();

Comment: You need to add this info to the question. Also your question is not really about c++ it is about the API that is giving an error. You might want to tag the question with whatever API it is.

Comment: Ok, I changed the way you like to see. Is that OK now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listBox2->Items->Add( System::Runtime::InteropServices::
    Marshal::PtrToStringUni( IntPtr( tmp.str().c_str() ) ) );
```

It is better to use managed System::String class in .NET application, than unmanaged string and stream. Don't mix managed and unmanaged types if this is not absolutely necessary.

This is the code from my test project:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             std::wostringstream s;
             s << L"test";

             listBox1->Items->Add( System::Runtime::InteropServices::
                 Marshal::PtrToStringUni( IntPtr( (void*)s.str().c_str() ) ) );

         }
```

Comment: what do you mean with marshal? Cause my IntelliSense of VS2012 don't show me a result to this keyword... Do I have to include a special header file or is it just wrong? Intellisense show me MarshalByRefObject, MarshalByValueComponent ...

Comment: Marshal class belongs to System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace. This class contains managed/unmanaged conversion methods.

Comment: Now I tried it again and is still not working... actually I think there must be an easier way or isn't it like that?

Comment: The Error is now: "Error C2440 <function-style-cast>: const wchar_t can not convert in System::IntPtr" do you have an clue?

Comment: @user1557170: the easy way is not to use Windows Forms. Use any other UI framework (MFC, Qt, wxWidgets, WTL etc.), but not Windows Forms. Or learn .NET first. Many programming start to work with Windows Forms in C++, but this is another language - C++/CLI.

Comment: Hey Alex, I have programmed a bluetooth scanner based on visual studio win api. Can you recommend my a good and easy ui framework, where I can include my existing Bluetooth Scanner?

Comment: Now its working, but it's still very complicated. My Main problem was to find a good UI Framework for my existing source code.

Comment: @user1557170: Windows forms is NOT a good UI framework. The only reason programmers use it is that this is the only framework included in VC++ Express Edition. I don't know your requirements and your previous experience. If you know MFC and it is available in your VC++, use it.

Comment: I don't have requairements of using frameworks - the only thing is it has to look good.

Comment: There a so much frameworks and tools in c++ I don't have a good overview of it. My c++ skills are not bad but not so well like yours :-)